# Laravel foreach multiple data

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

This is how I wish to be
[image]
Actual
[image]
Status gets printed 3 times

I return this objects from my controller:

```
return view('ViewTicket') ->with('tickets', $tickets)
        ->with('user', $user)
        ->with('priority', $priority)
        ->with('status', $status)
        ->with('type', $type);
```

However I want to print the respective fields like in my view:

```
   @foreach ($tickets as $t)
   <tr> 
    <td> {{$t->id}} </td>
    @foreach ($user as $u)

     @if($t->user_id==$u->Id)
    <td>{{ $u->UserName }}</td>
  @endif
    @endforeach
```

Even this doesnt solve my problem.Is there any way to avoid the loop inside the loop to get these data?The goal is to get respective fields for each ticket

If I `dd($user)` it returns 3 values okay
when I loop in my view it displays 9 values,which means it loops 3 times the lements

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You're confusing a query's `with` method with that on the view.

Comment: @EmilePels how can I return the data and use only one foreach

Comment: Have you tried using eager relationships? Something like: `$thickets = Ticket::with('user')->get();` and then in your loop just write `$ticket->user->UserName` without the additional foreach and if.

Answer (score -1):

**ASSUMPTIONS**

- `$tickets` is a collection of `ticket` objects.
- `$user` is a collection of `user` objects.

**CODE**

```
@foreach ($tickets as $t)
   <tr> 
    @foreach ($user as $u)
     @if($t->user_id == $u->Id)
        <td> {{$t->id}} </td>
        <td>{{ $u->UserName }}</td>
     @endif
    @endforeach
   </tr>
@endforeach
```

Comment: I want to use only one foreach

Comment: Ok, but can you explain how you wish to relate `$ticket` and `$user` ? What equalities you want to focus on?

Comment: both of them,they are selections of different tables

Comment: Can you please edit your post and give some input / output examples?

Comment: @EmilePels No, that;s not exactly the same code. In OP's code, the ticket `id` will get printed for all the ticket rows. Same is not the case with mine. It will only print when there is match with `user's` id. Also, the OP has made changes to make it look similar to mine. Initially it had `=` instead of `==`

Comment: @RandomUser Sorry but you can't post an image and expect us to understand it. It's still unclear. What is `actual status`  and how many times it should get printed? Why you want to use a single foreach loop instead of 2 nested loops?

Comment: = or == doesn't solve my problem here are nested loops

Comment: it should get printed only once per row,now it gets printed as many ticket items there are...

Comment: @RandomUser I am not saying it should solve your problem. I am saying you need to be clear. From what I understand, you want to print `ticket` only once when there is a match with the `user`. Am I correct?

Comment: Ok, so what is my code in the answer giving you? It should work. What is the output you are getting?

Comment: I already told you, it gets printed as many ticket items there are..in the same row ex if there are 4 items users name gets printed 4 times in the first row

Comment: In your question, you mentioned `The goal is to get respective fields for each ticket`. So, you have to loop for each ticket.  Also, are you saying there are many tickets for a single user?

Comment: check my comment above,maybe

Comment: Ok, I checked and if a `user's name` gets printed 4 times in the first row, it means that `$user` has a duplicate entries. Can you show me the eloquent query  for `$user` ? You can edit your post for this.

Comment: it doesn't have duplicate entries,there are no eloquent for this

Comment: How is `$user` having any values? Can you show us that? You have to give more details, else there is no point. What is `$tickets` ? Does `tickets` have many to one relation with model `User` ? You will also need to provide some DB table values of both `tickets` and `user`, exact output of how you wish the table should be(with exact values). I am asking because I can't keep guessing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171933/discussion-between-vivek-23-and-randomuser).